# Is it bad to have large objects on the heap?

Tags: c++

what are the consequences (if any) of having big objects stored on the heap rather than in the stack? I remember reading that it was preferable to have the bigger objects on the stack to limit the heap fragmentation... is that true?
thanks

edit : question comes from a game I'm making where my basic object that will have all the informations about textures, entities etc will be most likely created on the heap, I don't really have any idea of its size, we could assume something like 300 MB

Comment: What do you mean by big objects, stack isn't unlimited either.

Comment: Really large objects don't fit on the stack.  And fragmentation is determined by a lot of factors other than size.

Comment: Another option is to allocate some memory statically and put the Large Object in there.

Comment: For me "BIG" objects are not fitting on stack. To me answer is : *"usually stack is so limited, that big objects simply do NOT fit there and heap is only possible place"* . As others said , "big" is subjective.

Comment: thanks guys, seems like I had it wrong since the beginning...

Comment: If there's only one such object for the entire run of your program, you might consider just declaring it statically (at file or class scope) rather than allocating it on the heap.  Such an object is allocated once when your program starts, and cannot be deallocated until your program terminates.  If that fits your intended usage, then using either the stack or the heap is not useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally no.

It depends on the implementation, but on many systems the stack is much more limited in size than the heap.  Heap fragmentation is typically going to be an issue if you have a large number of (small) objects allocated on the heap.  It also tends to be caused by certain patterns of allocation *and deallocation*.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep in mind that stack is limited. The size can be configured on some environment but it also has drawbacks. If your object are short lived, they can reside on the stack but to be able to keep them for a long time, you have to create them and keep calling function and pass them as parameters because when the scope ends, your object is going out the window.

Following your edit, there's no way you're going to store an object of 300 MB on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You should decide where to put objects based on what their storage duration should be more so than what their size will be; however, as the stack is fairly limited, creating a large object on it is sometimes not a good idea and it may be necessary/more future-proof to `new` it and put the pointer to it in a `scoped_ptr`.

If you have enough big objects to cause significant heap fragmentation, or if you have an object that is so big as to be a significant factor by itself (to be honest, I'm not sure this is even possible), are you sure your design is right?  Note also that your objects are likely to be smaller than the storage your containers use, and that storage (except that of `std::array`s) is all dynamically allocated, i.e. on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

In general, large objects *should* be created on the heap. The stack should generally be used only for small objects relevant to a particular stack context.